# Limit an object's property to have a value based on another property in nested type

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Limit an object's property to have a value based on another property in nested type.

```
interface AMap {
  alpha: "a" | "b" | "c";
  beta: "x" | "y";
  gamma: "p" | "q" | "r";
};

type AType<T extends keyof AMap = keyof AMap> = {
  type: T;
  content: AMap[T];
  sub?: AType;
};

const a: AType = {
  type: "alpha",
  content: "a",
  sub: {
    type: "beta",
    content: "c"
  }
});
```

I want `content` property to have values corresponding to its `type` property.
I figured out to do this for top level object using function and generics but that did not work for nested objects, `content` was allowing every value.

**eg.**

```
const a: AType = {
  type: "alpha",
  content: "a", // "a" | "b" | "c"
  sub: {
    type: "beta",
    content: "x", // "x" | "y"
    sub: {
      type: "beta",
      content: "q", // "p" | "q" | "r"
    }
  }
});
```